# Delphi Resourcestring and Const expressions

Tags: delphi, resourcestring

I am trying to set a Tab char for a resource string as follows

```
const
  Tab : string = Chr( 9 );

resourcestring
      xmlversion = Tab + '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
      codetemplate = Chr( 9 ) + '<codetemplate xmlns="http://schemas.borland.com/Delphi/2005/codetemplates" version="1.0.0">';
```

The fist resourcestring does not work. The compiler returns ' E2026 Constant expression expected'.

The second line of code compiles alright. It is just a concat with the same code as Tab.

Comment: Do not specify type by your constant. Define it like `Tab = Chr(9);`. Or add typecast like `xmlversion = string(Tab) + ..`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration

```
const
  Tab : string = <whatever>;
```

disqualifies `Tab` to be used in constant expression at compile time, as internally it is more like an initialized, write protected variable. Remove the type and it should work.

Comment: Indeed, `const Tab = #9;` or `const Tab = Chr(9);` will do.

Comment: Ahh another Delphi quirk. Just another Brick In The Wall. I shall remember.

Comment: Fwiw, `typed constants` were in the original Turbo Pascal on which Delphi was based.